# Pytesseract not recognizing text even though it is visible in the picture

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have an image from which I want to extract text.

[image: text_image]

I am using following code to extract text.

```
pytesseract.image_to_string(text_image, config='-l eng --psm 7')
```

However, the output is wrong 80% of the time and it detects output like "mE Smart Meter Gateway" or "RTE Smart Meter Gateway". Mainly the issue is in the detection of the first two characters. I am using python3. Any help in improving the detection of the text will be appreciated.

Comment: Try applying some threshold before finding text

Comment: I did try applying threshold, however it makes the "LTE" part totally black. I am using following code to threshold.


`cv2.threshold(text_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)`

Comment: Try `adaptiveThresholding` instead.

Comment: `adaptiveThresholding` did the trick. Thanks @Markus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adaptiveThresholding, I was able to read the text.
First blur the image.

`blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(text_image, (7, 7), 0)`

Apply adaptivethresholding.

`thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 21, 4)`

Finally, extract the text.

`text = pytesseract.image_to_string(thresh, config='-l eng --psm 7')`